# Code working in TypeScript 3.3 broken in 3.5+, why?

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors

I've just migrated my codebase from TypeScript 3.3 to 3.6 and found that the following code does not compile anymore:

```ts
declare const enum Api_Request_Type {
    submit_chat_message = 1,
    pull_chat_messages = 2,
    battle_cheat = 50,
    get_collection_page = 12,

}

type Api_Request = {
    type: Api_Request_Type.submit_chat_message

    request: {
        message: string
    }

    response: {
        messages: string[]
    }
} | {
    type: Api_Request_Type.pull_chat_messages

    request: {}

    response: {
        messages: string[]
    }
} | {
    type: Api_Request_Type.battle_cheat

    request: {
        cheat: string
        selected_unit_id: number
    }

    response: {
    }
} | {
    type: Api_Request_Type.get_collection_page

    request: {
        page: number
    }

    response: object[]
}

type Find_By_Type<Union, Type> = Union extends { type: Type } ? Union : never;
type Find_Request<T> = Find_By_Type<Api_Request, T>["request"]
type Find_Response<T> = Find_By_Type<Api_Request, T>["response"]


function api_request_callback<T extends Api_Request_Type>(type: T, data: Find_Request<T>, callback: (res: Find_Response<T>) => void): void {
    fetch("api" + type, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    }).then(data => data.json()).then(data => {
        callback(data as Find_Response<T>);
    });
}

async function api_request<T extends Api_Request_Type>(type: T, data: Find_Request<T>): Promise<Find_Response<T>> {
    return new Promise<Find_Response<T>>((resolve) => {
        api_request_callback(type, data, (abc) => {});
    });
}
```

And the error for it:

```
Argument of type '(abc: (Find_By_Type<{ type: Api_Request_Type.submit_chat_message; request: { message: string; }; response: { messages: string[]; }; }, T> | Find_By_Type<{ type: Api_Request_Type.pull_chat_messages; request: {}; response: { messages: string[]; }; }, T> | Find_By_Type<...> | Find_By_Type<...>)["response"]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(res: (Find_By_Type<{ type: Api_Request_Type.submit_chat_message; request: { message: string; }; response: { messages: string[]; }; }, T> | Find_By_Type<{ type: Api_Request_Type.pull_chat_messages; request: {}; response: { messages: string[]; }; }, T> | Find_By_Type<...> | Find_By_Type<...>)["response"]) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'abc' and 'res' are incompatible.
    Type 'Find_By_Type<{ type: Api_Request_Type.submit_chat_message; request: { message: string; }; response: { messages: string[]; }; }, T>["response"] | Find_By_Type<{ type: Api_Request_Type.pull_chat_messages; request: {}; response: { messages: string[]; }; }, T>["response"] | Find_By_Type<...>["response"] | Find_By_Type<....' is not assignable to type 'Find_By_Type<{ type: Api_Request_Type.submit_chat_message; request: { message: string; }; response: { messages: string[]; }; }, T>["response"] & Find_By_Type<{ type: Api_Request_Type.pull_chat_messages; request: {}; response: { messages: string[]; }; }, T>["response"] & Find_By_Type<...>["response"] & Find_By_Type<....'.
      Type 'Find_By_Type<{ type: Api_Request_Type.submit_chat_message; request: { message: string; }; response: { messages: string[]; }; }, T>["response"]' is not assignable to type 'Find_By_Type<{ type: Api_Request_Type.submit_chat_message; request: { message: string; }; response: { messages: string[]; }; }, T>["response"] & Find_By_Type<{ type: Api_Request_Type.pull_chat_messages; request: {}; response: { messages: string[]; }; }, T>["response"] & Find_By_Type<...>["response"] & Find_By_Type<....'.
        Type '{ messages: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Find_By_Type<{ type: Api_Request_Type.submit_chat_message; request: { message: string; }; response: { messages: string[]; }; }, T>["response"] & Find_By_Type<{ type: Api_Request_Type.pull_chat_messages; request: {}; response: { messages: string[]; }; }, T>["response"] & Find_By_Type<...>["response"] & Find_By_Type<....'.
          Type '{ messages: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Find_By_Type<{ type: Api_Request_Type.get_collection_page; request: { page: number; }; response: object[]; }, T>["response"]'.
            Type '{ messages: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'object[]'.
              Type 'Find_By_Type<{ type: Api_Request_Type.submit_chat_message; request: { message: string; }; response: { messages: string[]; }; }, T>["response"]' is not assignable to type 'Find_By_Type<{ type: Api_Request_Type.get_collection_page; request: { page: number; }; response: object[]; }, T>["response"]'.
                Type 'Find_By_Type<{ type: Api_Request_Type.submit_chat_message; request: { message: string; }; response: { messages: string[]; }; }, T>' is not assignable to type 'Find_By_Type<{ type: Api_Request_Type.get_collection_page; request: { page: number; }; response: object[]; }, T>'.
                  Type 'Find_By_Type<{ type: Api_Request_Type.submit_chat_message; request: { message: string; }; response: { messages: string[]; }; }, T>["response"]' is not assignable to type 'object[]'.
                    Type '{ messages: string[]; }' is missing the following properties from type 'object[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more.
```

The error is rather cryptic due to it containing all the type information, but basically it's saying that there is a type mismatch between the `abc` in `(abc) => {}` and the `res: FindResponse<T>` in the `api_request_callback` signature. This code used to compile in 3.3 and makes sense to me why it would.

I'm sure the error is legit but I just don't understand why and how would I go about fixing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh, this is probably another victim of [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769), a known [breaking change in TS3.5](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#fixes-to-unsound-writes-to-indexed-access-types).  The change enforces the idea that it's only safe to write the *intersection* of property types to the *union* of the properties. For example, if I have a variable `v` of type `{x: A, y: B}` and a value `k` of type `"x" | "y"`, if I *read* `v[k]`, I get something of type `A | B`, but it's not safe to *write* a value of type `A | B` to `v[k]`.  It's only safe to write a value of type `A & B`.  That means the lookup type `{x: A, y: B}["x" | "y"]` is `A | B` when you *read* it, and `A & B` when you *write* it.  Note that "read" also means "output from a function", and "write" also means "input into a function".

This change has had many *good* effects, but also a few nasty ones.  One of which is that  the statement `v[k] = v[k]` suddenly becomes an error if `k` is of a union type.  That's actually pretty catastrophic if enforced everywhere, so [one loophole they left open](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769#issuecomment-498428559) is if both `v` and `k` are generic types, then the compiler thinks `v[k]` is the same type on both read and write.

So any workaround I can find here will either involve [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to force the compiler to bend to your will, or making your types generic enough to exploit the loophole.

---

If I look into issues filed about this, I see [microsoft/TypeScript#31833](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31833), entitled "3.5 Breaks function assignments that use a complex Discriminated Union Type".  That looks like exactly what's happening here.  It's listed as a bug, which is good, but I don't know if it will be fixed anytime soon.

---

Until then, let's try the workarounds.  First, assert our way out:

```
async function api_request<T extends Api_Request_Type>(
    type: T,
    data: Find_Request<T>
): Promise<Find_Response<T>> {
    return new Promise<Find_Response<T>>((resolve) => {
        api_request_callback(type, data, ((abc: Find_Response<T>) => { }) as any);
    });
}
```

That *works*, but it uses the yucky `any` type.  There are probably some slightly less unsafe assertions, but they are undoubtedly ugly.

---

The second is to make things more generic and exploit the loophole.  You're using the concrete `Api_Request` type and trying to index into its `"request"` and `"response"` properties.  Let's take everything that uses `Api_Request` and give it a generic parameter `A` that both extends  and defaults to `Api_Request`:

```
type Find_By_Type<Union, Type> = Union extends { type: Type } ? Union : never;
type Find_Request<T, A extends Api_Request = Api_Request> = Find_By_Type<A, T>["request"]
type Find_Response<T, A extends Api_Request = Api_Request> = Find_By_Type<A, T>["response"]

function api_request_callback<T extends Api_Request_Type, A extends Api_Request = Api_Request>(
    type: T,
    data: Find_Request<T, A>,
    callback: (res: Find_Response<T, A>) => void
): void {
    fetch("api" + type, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    }).then(data => data.json()).then(data => {
        callback(data as Find_Response<T, A>);
    });
}

async function api_request<T extends Api_Request_Type, A extends Api_Request = Api_Request>(
    type: T,
    data: Find_Request<T, A>
): Promise<Find_Response<T, A>> {
    return new Promise<Find_Response<T, A>>((resolve) => {
        api_request_callback(type, data, ((abc) => { }));
    });
}
```

Now the compiler is happy.  Of course when you actually use these types and functions, `A` will generally be inferred/defaulted to the concrete `Api_Request` type, which is exactly the same as what you were already doing.  But now you're doing it in a more roundabout way.  Hooray?

---

I'd probably just go with the assertion if I were you, since it changes your code very little.  But it's up to you.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-WYxXaibkxI82ZB-HE2bkz9h3Cs2OrgAiZ3YZd3coD2O1faa0fj6M7hNJ2eUv7MRc5ld+zUb1kAMylosLSBANTXzhAjiC8AA1qOxZlqwlYdPO-yVDmAAU7zktmiS2KQuggO0k7gcwB4IYo8DfpQv5-u0UF7KhO6CHuGAHgAlN4eadvQsqbJR7R0bKrqKA+EDYNoUHLu+3DLkgADUNayFm2onJxWj0HKSDLgACgA8gAyhIy5YfMKjSVI7QAFJKQpAByAwXPy3APlIUFIdgICUepJDFJRfTYBEwCWchNFkMhfRBlAjBQZRjnOawbnWR54m2DhP4IH+IUgG+VZoWRGoUWOlF9vMDnpfZrIgFAUjAPASBPgVtpFnxvBroBpblqBc5UhBsjQbBtYSHZxBWShR5DvVGFjox7RyZg9DqBRiXqqiB55uFSC0NgbCYEWwAQAA7kgg3Ddwo2keN+5jtBRHQKk3bUSYU3vAo5WfpFeHRVBnxZh1WZQVBIAqPAJHdTtKU5idU0NtRuVvsAUhpQSoM6tsoD6HAiBIAA4qwWBmVIbybOQVA0HQBwsAqYE9aa9bTYM6iaDoYIGLkZhWO8wJOC45MQl4vhtUgdIMuEzLRPELOWgwaQvnanh5AUjyspGdUXrgZjTXBEsmkmAyqCToJuOC4y+pLnKCqcfLrD6SJfVq50LGrkK63im4BIS9l6jLtZy9SZpAg4dNk6rFPQI6xBrgiXszYbWtcli5thlbuoks1bR45LCts6EHO6H7PtsfMPLwkoJl64KSgQDa4qStK4iyh6irKhlScByn2VErbkdog7DXmrz1rpIW2TqwbJqBxi7pIAqXr65MleBiGoqhw8-ayF1U6nq2wCLpB+YZkW1UgVWeAiWiZoNkgzZz+2fddr2k-IGNI6tagQE1VWDcNGYt-YIeaEnjOKBXjekv3luU9jeRKYXygK+a9o4mmiA-J+x5pyVFnO-Vcht7ybGKgLMqH4Y7XXwlVYCFYb7nnlmaLMgDV7YJAXCMBuC4RNXmHBVq7wOofQlPjUcBCcws3QdFQixFp67mSv-Zhv0kAsVIP1AR9FSBV2IBxLiWgeJ8QEsJe64jFCQGctJdo8llKqRZgoTSpBtJID0oZYyuJkaxVsmDJyLlYoeQ6t5XyrkAoWOCh1MKxtiBsP-FYwGv8eFMNQD9LKthMqi02LlfKhUkGlTfKg8+QDiEPyTAQ2JtVyFiDIcaChMEqEtRZnQrhjCAE5mEetEaKZvETQKWdA2c0FqH1WsUzapTtp-18SgHM+09hHQgPw6aF1onUncTFBRj0kDPVevAbp-1wZWymRPAgxQgA)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation and fix, exactly what I was looking for! I did try to read through breaking changes in 3.5 but wasn't able to put pieces together since I'm not that well versed in advanced types

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps. let me know if you have any questions

```
export type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never
export type UnionMembersWith<T, K extends keyof UnionToIntersection<T>, VALUE> = Exclude<T, Exclude<T, Partial<Record<K, VALUE>>>>;


declare const enum Api_Request_Type {
    submit_chat_message = 1,
    pull_chat_messages = 2,
    battle_cheat = 50,
    get_collection_page = 12,

}

type Api_Request = {
    type: Api_Request_Type.submit_chat_message

    request: {
        message: string
    }

    response: {
        messages: string[]
    }
} | {
    type: Api_Request_Type.pull_chat_messages

    request: {}

    response: {
        messages: string[]
    }
} | {
    type: Api_Request_Type.battle_cheat

    request: {
        cheat: string
        selected_unit_id: number
    }

    response: {
    }
} | {
    type: Api_Request_Type.get_collection_page

    request: {
        page: number
    }

    response: object[]
}

type Find_By_Type<Union, Type> = Union extends { type: Type } ? Union : never;

type Test = Find_By_Type<Api_Request_Type.battle_cheat, { type: Api_Request_Type.battle_cheat }>

type Find_Request<T> = Find_By_Type<Api_Request, T>["request"]
type Find_Response<T> = UnionMembersWith<Api_Request, "type", {type: T}>["response"]


function api_request_callback<T extends Api_Request_Type>(type: T, data: Find_Request<T>, callback: (res: Find_Response<T>) => void): void {
    fetch("api" + type, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    }).then(data => data.json()).then(data => {
        callback(data as Find_Response<T>);
    });
}

type test = Api_Request["type"]

async function api_request<T extends Api_Request["type"]>(
    type: T,
    data: Find_Request<T>
): Promise<Find_Response<T>> {
    return new Promise<Find_Response<T>>((resolve) => {
        api_request_callback(type, data, (abc) => {
            return 5 as any;
        });
    });
}


api_request(Api_Request_Type.battle_cheat, {cheat: "", selected_unit_id: 5})
```